# Por qué se queda atorada la consola de c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hice un programa que calcula la suma de factoriales hasta el número que escriba el usuario (1!+2!+3!+...n!).

Al terminarlo y ejecutarlo, la consola se queda paralizada tras escribir el valor "n".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int n, acum=1, result=0;
    cout << "Ingrese un valor para n y hallaremos la suma de factoriales hasta n.\n"; cin >>n;
    
    for (int i=1; i<=n;i++)
    {
        
        for (int a=1; i<=i;i++)
        {
            acum = acum * i;
        }
        result = result + acum;
        acum=1;
    }
    
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Y bueno, si lo ejecuto y le doy de valor 5 a n, se queda paralizada la pantalla de la consola. No sé por qué.

```
Ingrese un valor para n y hallaremos la suma de factoriales hasta n.
5
```

Agradecería sugerencias y explicaciones ante este suceso.
Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: En el `for( )` interno, te has equivocado de variable. Declaras una llamada `a`, pero vuelves a trabajar con `i`. Debería ser `for( int a = 1; a <= i; ++a )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes problemas en tu segundo bucle `for`, ya que pones `for(int a=1; i<=i; i++)`, sigues usando `i` cuando deberías usar `a`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    int n, acum = 1, result = 0;
    cout << "Ingrese un valor para n y hallaremos la suma de factoriales hasta n.\n" 
    cin >> n;
 
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int a=1; a<=i; a++) {
            //acum = acum * a; //lo mismo de abajo
            acum *= a;
        }
        //result = result + acum; //lo mismo de abajo
        result += acum;
        acum = 1;
    }
 
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n;i++)
```

Es un bucle infinito, la variable `i` **siempre** será menor **o igual** a si misma. Por otro lado, calcular el factorial de cada número cada vez que quieres sumarlo no es lo más eficiente. Calcula ese factorial, guárdalo, y usa el pre-cálculo para hacer la suma:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

auto factorial = [](int n) {
    // Crea un vector de 'n' elementos inicializados a cero.
    std::vector<int> valor(n, 0);
    // Rellena el vector con valores ascendentes desde 1
    std::generate(valor.begin(), valor.end(), [v = 0]() mutable { return ++v; });
    // Multiplica entre si los elementos del vector
    return std::accumulate(valor.begin(), valor.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>{});
};

// Crea un vector de 'n' elementos inicializados a cero.
std::vector<int> factoriales(n, 0);
for (int indice = 1; indice <= n; ++indice)
{
    // Calcula el factorial de 'indice' y lo guarda en el vector.
    factoriales[indice - 1] = factorial(indice);
    std::cout << "Suma de factoriales hasta " << indice << " = "
        // Suma todos los factoriales desde el primero hasta el 'indice'
        << std::accumulate(factoriales.begin(), factoriales.begin() + indice, 0) << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVG7joMwEKzxV6xyRUB5KFwZCD9xZS7FxjjEkllHxqaJ8u2cDYRwD@k67@zM2DPmt9uGK6Sq694kceVKAbnUjTUC64K9MFSVNtJev4HkamEkn0MXR9xKTajmaCu41aZgTJKFGiXFCbuzKEyUsaix5X7PJUFRhJlF6KyGCwaRRAUHOJ7inpyAlw38wTP3cAEtKm1iWsMuyZ77SpAwaEXcL7dnUYVr1wN3K6gMw7H15rtTnEDtLJ6VgDsYYZ0hWK3aDB6934j0tsi5q536zzhdD3RPtfKmpGj6l957w0fI@CvElFc0U5SLNtAnl1RKLvxj0@x5zg@@LP/MYUxYFKqZmRxH3gbSkxdOm3gUTE1x7SzkOSw@XI3g/2tmAldsLMIi7J/3eqb3W3h55M8/W5mJX938AcJqNAxRg@nyk5ahHN/NWPguY4@uS9/ZFw)</kbd>.